# How to choose first working image source from array in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'm mapping some images from the API response, and they come with an array of five `img` sources(urls). By default, `src` of the image should be first `url` from the given array, but in some cases that `url` is broken, and should be replaced with the next working `url` from the array. I've tried doing something like this:

```js
<img src={snapshots[0]} alt="" onError={(e) => this.onError(e, snapshots)} />

imageExists = url => {
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
        
        if (img.width !== 0) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
        
      }

onError = (e, snapshots) => {
        
       if (this.imageExists(snapshots[1])) {
            e.target.src = snapshots[1]
       } else if (this.imageExists(snapshots[2])) {
            e.target.src = snapshots[2]
        } else if (this.imageExists(snapshots[3])) {
           e.target.src = snapshots[3]
        } else if (this.imageExists(snapshots[4])) {
            e.target.src = snapshots[4]
        } else {
            e.target.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/400x300'
       }

        
    }
```

But sometimes this checking method works, sometimes it doesn't, it just skips to the placeholder image, even if there are working urls. Any advice?

Comment: If the size of image is big, it will take time to load. By that time, your check `img.width !== 0` will have been processed and would return false

Comment: Add `onLoad` handler to `let img` and if its called, remove handler from other images and set src of current image

Comment: @Rajesh I think the question seems little bit different then the one you marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Justcode Thats true. However, the real issue is in checking if the image is loaded or not. Hence, I marked it as dupe. If you strongly believe its not match, i'll reopen it and share its link

Comment: @Rajesh lets wait for op first